# Configure gulp task to move files to subfolder

Tags: gulp, reactjs

I need to move compiled jsx->js files from:

`./Scripts/lib/xyz/components` (jsx starts here)

to

`./Scripts/lib/xyz/components/build` (.js should end up here)

My current gulpfile is

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var react = require('gulp-react');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var notify = require('gulp-notify');

var libPath = "./Scripts/lib";


gulp.task("default", function() {
  var errorHandler = function(err) {
    notify.onError({
      title: "Compile Error",
      message: "<%= error.fileName %> <%= error.message %>"
    })(err);
  };

  gulp.src(libPath+'/**/*.jsx')
    .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: errorHandler}))
    .pipe(watch(libPath+'/**/*.jsx',{base: libPath}))
    .pipe(react())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(libPath));
});
```

This gulpfile works, but it copies js files to the same folder. I would like to move them to /build subfolder. I just don't know which plugin i need :(

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [gulp-rename](https://github.com/hparra/gulp-rename).

Something like this should work:

```js
gulp.src(libPath+'/**/*.jsx')
    .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: errorHandler}))
    .pipe(watch(libPath+'/**/*.jsx',{base: libPath}))
    .pipe(react())
    .pipe(rename(function (path) {
        path.dirname += "/build";
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(libPath));
```